# Assign attribute name to all __init__ attributes

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment

The below results in `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

```
class New:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.long_name_a = None
        self.long_name_b = None
        self.add_value()
    
    def add_value(self):
        for att in self.__dict__:
            self.att = att

new = New()
assert new.long_name_a == 'long_name_a'
```

Putting aside option `self.long_name_a = 'long_name_a'` or
`self.long_name_a = add_value('long_name_a')`, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you cannot modify a dict while you iterate over it. But it really isn't clear what you are *trying* to accomlish in `add_value`... what do you think `self.att = att` *does*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code does not do what you expect.  That creates a new member called `self.att`.  What you meant to write was:

```
    def add_value(self):
        for att in self.__dict__:
            setattr( self, att, att )
```